# Read particular XML

Tags: c#, xml, windows, windows-phone-8

I have this XML:

```
<palinsesto>
<giorno label="Mer" data="2014/12/31">
<canale description="Premium Cinema" id="KE">
<prg Pod="N" Nettv="N" orafine="06:30" orainizio="06:00" replica="No" primaTv="No">
<durata duratapixel="30">30</durata>
<tipologia>Type</tipologia>
<titolo>evento iniziato ieri</titolo>
<descrizione>--</descrizione>
<audio sottotitoli="No subtitles" audioType="Mono" doppioAudio="One language">Not used</audio>
<parentalRating>LIBERO DA DIVIETI</parentalRating>
<trafficLight/>
<anno>--</anno>
<paese>--</paese>
```

and i need to read the value in prg class and palinsesto class, i try in this mode but not work

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
    var canal = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("description", "canale")).FirstOrDefault();
    var date = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("data", "giorno")).FirstOrDefault();
    var title = doc.Descendants(XName.Get("titolo", "prg")).FirstOrDefault();
```

return always error

Comment: What is the error? Your XML is currently invalid. It is missing a root element.

Comment: As @YuvalItzchakov says, your XML is not valid XML. You should use XDocument.Parse() method and pass in the string, pay attention to the error messages and rectify your input data before you can start querying the result.

Comment: 'System.Exception' on System.Windows.ni.dll , the xml is not my i need only read the value, with php is simple but on C# no =(

Comment: @user3477026: No, it's *very* simple with C# - you're just going about it incorrectly. It's not clear what you mean by "the xml is not my" - please clarify, and make sure the XML you provide in the question is a valid sample. Also, if you're getting an exception you should *always* give the details (stack trace, error message, any inner exceptions) in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not require this `XName` [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname(v=vs.110).aspx) here - the second parameter is used to provide a namespace, which isn't present in the xml you've provided. I believe you are confusing attributes and `xmlns` namespaces. In order to obtain the attributes, use `.Attributes()`, as follows:

```
var canal = doc.Descendants("canale").Attributes("description").FirstOrDefault();
var date = doc.Descendants("giorno").Attributes("data").FirstOrDefault();
var title = doc.Descendants("prg").Attributes("titolo").FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've misunderstood names, attributes and elements. It looks like you just want something like:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
var root = doc.Root;
var canal = root.Element("canale").Attribute("description").Value;
var date = root.Element("giorno").Attribute("data").Value;
var title = root.Element("titolo").Value;
```

However:

- Currently none of your first three elements are closed, which would cause the above to fail; it's not clear what your *real* XML would look like. You should indent it to show the intended structure.
- Your date is not represented in the normal way for XML - if you're in control of the XML, it would be better to have a value of `2014-12-31`
- The above code assumes you just want the first element from the root. If that's not the case, you'll need to give us more information